# ubuntu 16.04 laptop connects to wireless router but not always to network

Tags: networking

I can connect to my wireless router but sometimes I cannot connect to the local network (or internet).   It seems pretty random as to whether or not I can connect.  Sometimes it resets if I switch to another network then back, or power down then reboot.  Sometimes not.  Any thoughts on the solution or the next step(s) to take?  Or more info that may be needed?   Thank you very much for any advice!   Here's some more info which might be relevant:

When I cannot connect I cannot get on the internet nor ping any IP addresses even in my local network (even 192.168.1.1 which is the router IP addr).  This doesn't seem to happen if I connect to other wireless routers or AP's.   Other devices on my local network (windows PC's, iPhones, Roku's) all seem to work fine all the time.  So the problem is specific to my linux laptop and my wireless router and/or network.

I've got:

ubuntu 16.04

ipv4, ipv6 settings set to automatic (DCHP), automatic
router is D-link DIR-813

When network IS working OK:

```
$ ifconfig wlan

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:02:2a:6e:f6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:2ff:fe2a:6ef6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8571 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5650 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6284311 (6.2 MB)  TX bytes:860449 (860.4 KB)
```

When network IS NOT working:

```
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:02:2a:6e:f6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:2ff:fe2a:6ef6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94503 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51798 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:31525953 (31.5 MB)  TX bytes:9380130 (9.3 MB)
```

Any thoughts on the solution or the next step(s) to take?  Or more info that may be needed?   Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: What is the difference between ifconfig outputs. I've looked and looked and don't see it. Edit your question to add the output of `sudo lshw -C net`.

Answer (score 0):

For WPA identification (substitute `<wifi name>` and `<wifi key>`)

```
nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlan1 ssid <wifi name>
nmcli connection modify <wifi name> wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli connection modify <wifi name> wifi-sec.psk <wifi key>
nmcli -p connection up <wifi name>
```